# How to solve the following recurrences and find a Theta bound

Tags: recurrence, big-o

1. T(n) = T(n-1)+n^c
2. T(n) = T(n-1)+c^n

where c is a constant

Comment: I think you should give it a try yourself first. These are basic recurrences and there are various techniques to solve them. But instead of asking for a solution here, let us know about your tries first. You can start doing it intuitively. For instance, in the first problem, at every step of recursion, you are reducing the the problem size by 1, solving the (not so) smaller problem recursively and then spending some more time (polynomial in n) to rearrange/combine that solution. Does that tell you more? Can you draw a tree depicting the recursion?

Comment: T(n)=T(n-1)+n^c    ,
T(n-1) = T(n-2)+(n-1)^c   ,
T(n-2) = T(n-3)+(n-2)^c   ,
T(n) = T(n-3)+(n-2)^c+(n-1)^c+n^c       ,
T(n)=T(n-k)+(n-k+1)^c+(n-k+2)^c+n^c   ,
let n-k=1
T(n)=T(1)+2^c+3^c+n^c
T(n) = C log n
T(n)= Theta(logn)

Comment: T(n)=T(n-1)+c^n              ,
T(n-1) = T(n-2)+c^(n-1)        ,
T(n-2) = T(n-3)+c^(n-2)          ,
T(n) = T(n-3)+c^(n-2)+c^(n-1)+c^n                    ,
T(n)=T(n-k)+c^(n-k+1)+c^(n-k+2)+c^n               ,
let n-k=1
T(n)=T(1)+c^2+c^3+c^n            ,
T(n) = T(1)+2log c+3logc+ nlogc                 ,
T(n) = Theta(n)
Is this correct too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you unroll the recursion, for the first case you will get:

```
1^c + 2^c + ... + (n-1)^c + n^c
```

which is a [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). It tells you that the complexity is `O(n^(c+1))`

The second one is:

```
c^1 + c^2 + ... + c^(n-1) + c^n
```

which is the [sum of geometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) and `O(c^n)`